# Conditonally RegEx replace

Tags: c++, regex, windows

I have a string:

```
std::string String = "<!\\[LOG\\[somestringhere\\]LOG\\]!><time=\"12:34:30.0+120\" date=\"9-14-2015\" component=\"mycomponenet\" context=\"\" type=\"1\" thread=\"0\" file=\"mxyfile.cpp\"><!\\[LOG\\[somestringhere\\]LOG\\]!><time=\"12:34:30.0+120\" date=\"9-14-2015\" component=\"mycomponenet\" context=\"\" type=\"1\" thread=\"0\" file=\"mxyfile.cpp\">";
```

I want to insert a `\n` char here `><![LOG[` after the `>` sign.

My code so far:

```
#include <regex>

const std::tr1::regex pattern( "(>|\")<!\\[LOG\\[" );
std::string replace = ">\n<![LOG[";
std::string newtext = std::tr1::regex_replace( String, pattern, replace );
std::cout << newtext << std::endl;
```

This works well, but there is unfortunately a little problem. Not every line end with a `>`. In some cases there stays `\"<!\\[LOG\\[` and not `><!\\[LOG\\[` as it should be.

If the last `>` is missing then the result will be `"\n<![LOG[` and not `>\n<![LOG[` as it should be.

So my question is, what is the easiest/best way to solve this? 
Should I somehow check if the pattern exists or not and then set the replacement string accordingly?

Hopefully it is understandable what I want.

Thanks.

**Update:**
Sorry, but as I see, I made a mistake, by how the string looks, and that caused some misunderstanding.
The string what in the logfile is(I read a logfile into an std::string and process that), is the following. This are actually two lines, but a Line break is missing, and thats what I want to insert.

Case1:
The string look like this:
`<![LOG[somestring]LOG]!><time="12:34:30.0+120" date="9-14-2015" component="mycomponent" context="" type="1" thread="0" file="myfile.cpp"><![LOG[somestring]LOG]!><time="12:34:30.0+120" date="9-14-2015" component="mycomponent" context="" type="1" thread="0" file="myfile.cpp">`

From this I would like to get as a result:
`<![LOG[somestring]LOG]!><time="12:34:30.0+120" date="9-14-2015" component="mycomponent" context="" type="1" thread="0" file="myfile.cpp">**LineBreakHere**
<![LOG[somestring]LOG]!><time="12:34:30.0+120" date="9-14-2015" component="mycomponent" context="" type="1" thread="0" file="myfile.cpp">`

Please Note where the Line break should be.

Case 2:
The string is almost the following:
`<![LOG[somestring]LOG]!><time="12:34:30.0+120" date="9-14-2015" component="mycomponent" context="" type="1" thread="0" file="myfile.cpp"<![LOG[somestring]LOG]!><time="12:34:30.0+120" date="9-14-2015" component="mycomponent" context="" type="1" thread="0" file="myfile.cpp"`

Please note, that there is a `>` missing after `file="myfile.cpp"`

If that is the case, I would like to get the same result as before:
`<![LOG[somestring]LOG]!><time="12:34:30.0+120" date="9-14-2015" component="mycomponent" context="" type="1" thread="0" file="myfile.cpp">**LineBreakHere and the missing > was also inserted**
<![LOG[somestring]LOG]!><time="12:34:30.0+120" date="9-14-2015" component="mycomponent" context="" type="1" thread="0" file="myfile.cpp"> **also inserted missing >**`

So basically, I want to insert a line break, and if there is a missing `>` I want to insert it too, if that is possible.

Comment: FYI: Raw string literals were invented for cases such as these.  Although I'm not answering your question, I highly encourage you to use the raw string literals so that you don't have to escape the special characters.  It may make the diagnosis easier: `std::string s1 = "\\n\\\\"` vs `std::string s2 = R"(\n\\)"`. _Incidentally, it's `std::regex` now, and not `std::tr1::regex`, assuming you're using an up-to-date compiler._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex should look like

```
"(>|\")<!\\\\\\[LOG\\\\\\["
```

The 4 slashes for `\` and 2 for escaping the square bracket. A better way to write regexps is with `R"(...)"` notation ("raw string literals"):

```
const std::regex pattern( R"((>|\")<!\\\[LOG\\\[)" );
```

And the code will be:

```
const std::regex pattern( R"((>|\")<!\\\[LOG\\\[)" );
std::string String = "<!\\[LOG\\[somestringhere\\]LOG\\]!><time=\"12:34:30.0+120\" date=\"9-14-2015\" component=\"mycomponenet\" context=\"\" type=\"1\" thread=\"0\" file=\"mxyfile.cpp\"><!\\[LOG\\[somestringhere\\]LOG\\]!><time=\"12:34:30.0+120\" date=\"9-14-2015\" component=\"mycomponenet\" context=\"\" type=\"1\" thread=\"0\" file=\"mxyfile.cpp\">";
std::string replace = "$1\n<![LOG[";
std::string newtext = std::regex_replace( String, pattern, replace );
std::cout << newtext << std::endl;
```

The `nextext` is

```
<!\[LOG\[somestringhere\]LOG\]!><time="12:34:30.0+120" date="9-14-2015" component="mycomponenet" context="" type="1" thread="0" file="mxyfile.cpp">
<![LOG[somestringhere\]LOG\]!><time="12:34:30.0+120" date="9-14-2015" component="mycomponenet" context="" type="1" thread="0" file="mxyfile.cpp">
```

Note that the replacement string now contains a back-reference `$1` to the first captured group (the one matched by the subpattern inside parentheses `(<|\")`, and we safely restore it inside the replacement. That is all I modified  together with the backslashes.

An [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/lMNwVA)

A [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kJ2jD7/1)

**UPDATE**:

You can use `R"((<!\[LOG\[[\s\S]*?\]!><[^<]*)(\">?))"` regex:

```
const std::regex pattern( R"((<!\[LOG\[[\s\S]*?\]!><[^<]*)(\">?))" );
std::string String = "<![LOG[somestring]LOG]!><time=\"12:34:30.0+120\" date=\"9-14-2015\" component=\"mycomponent\" context=\"\" type=\"1\" thread=\"0\" file=\"myfile.cpp\"<![LOG[somestring]LOG]!><time=\"12:34:30.0+120\" date=\"9-14-2015\" component=\"mycomponent\" context=\"\" type=\"1\" thread=\"0\" file=\"myfile.cpp\"";
std::string replace = "$1\">\n";
std::string newtext = std::regex_replace( String, pattern, replace );
std::cout << newtext << std::endl;
```

[Ideone demo](http://ideone.com/hzoxbv)

**REGEX EXPLANATION:**

The pattern has got 2 capturing groups: the one capturing the beginning of `<![LOG[` and up to the end of the next node (`(<!\[LOG\[[\s\S]*?\]!><[^<]*)`), and another one capturing the quote with closing angle bracket or a quote only `(">|")`.

- `(<!\[LOG\[` - Match `<![LOG[` literally (start of first capture group)
- `[\s\S]*?` - Match 0 or more any characters (even a newline)
- `\]!><` - Match `]!><` literally
- `[^<]*)` - Match 0 or more characters other than `<` (end of the first capture group)
- `(\">|\")` - Matches and captures `">` or `"`. You can write it as `(\">?)`.

Comment: Your answer is almost perfect. I updated my question. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: Now I just have to understand it :) Thanks you :)

Comment: I will write an explanation when my family goes to bed